# How to generate C.UTF-8 locale on CentOS6

Tags: centos, locale

Failing to generate C.UTF-8 locale on CentOS6 :

```bash
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
# localedef -v -c -i C -f UTF-8 C.UTF-8
cannot open locale definition file `C': No such file or directory
```

How can I do that on CentOS6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need to provide a compatible `/usr/share/i18n/locales/C` file, because RHEL / CentOS 6.x does not have one for the C locale.

I think when RHEL 6 was new, RedHat's recommendation used to be "use `en_US.utf8` instead". And indeed, in RHEL 6 the `en_US` locale provides 24-hour time representation, if that's what you're after.

Also, RHEL 6 seems to prefer the `.utf8` form to specify the UTF-8 character encoding instead of `.UTF-8`, as evidenced both `locale -a` and `localedef --list-archive`.

Comment: CentOS7 also complains saying `cannot open locale definition file "C': No such file or directory"`, I think I'll stick using `LANG=en_US.utf8` in my `.bash_profile`. Thanks.

Comment: How does one "provide a compatible /usr/share/i18n/locales/C file"? I have exactly same problem with CentOS 7.

Comment: @arrowd Your options would be to either download the source RPM that builds the `glibc-common` package (which includes the `/usr/share/i18n/locales/*` files), and build your own definition for the `C.UTF-8` locale, or if there is another locale that has suitable contents but wrong name, using `/usr/share/locale/locale.alias` to make `C.UTF-8` refer to a suitable existing locale. Note that edits to `/usr/share/locale/locale.alias` *will* get overwritten whenever `glibc-common` is updated, since it is not marked as a configuration file within the RPM package metadata.